# Is it possible for your APP network status indicator to be turned on by something other than your own App?

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, networking, statusbar

I have couple method that depend on the network status indicator being hidden or not based on my App. I was wondering if it is possible something outside of your App control is able to turn it off or on. Any clarification will be appreciated. I downloaded an App in background and received an email in the background the indicator didn't show.

Answer (score 0):

If you're referring to the `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` property of `UIApplication`, I don't believe any outside application will manipulate that property, since it is specific to the running application.

I assume you're asking because of [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/25692114/772156), and I would recommend, like others have, not to use this to determine whether a network call has completed or not. I would put the code you want to execute at completion in a callback or delegate, depending on how the call is made. Attaching it to the `networkActivityIndicatorVisible` property can lead to problems if you have code in the future that shows and hides this, but you don't want this method to execute anymore.